# Discord.js - get string after first word

Tags: javascript, string, discord

im making a fun little dad joke discord bot that replies to someone saying "hi + word after im". So, when they say "im okay", it replies "hi okay, im dad".

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("im")) {
    message.reply("Hi " + message.content)
   }
});
```

everything is fine until it replies. I get **Hi im "message after"**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim the value, removing first 3 chars which stand for `im` .

```
message.reply("Hi " + message.content.slice(3) + ", im dad")
```